# Need to convert from XML to HTML in java

Tags: java, html, xml, xml-parsing

Please give me suggestion as i need to convert from XML to HTML in java without using XSLT. As i was searching in the web but everywhere it was showing can convert from xml to html with use of only xslt/xsl?

Please guyz give me some suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean XML to HTML, exactly??

Comment: i had one xml file which i need to convert and show into html page or in html format.As i dont have any xsl file for the same.

Comment: NFE answer below is the best solution for this simple usecase. Keep XML in original format and use a HTML page with javascript to parse and present it in the browser.

Comment: *"..without using XSLT."*  Why 'without'?  It is an excellent tool for the job.

Comment: @AndrewThompson---as i dont have any xsl and dont know how to write xsl for the same.And i dont have enough time to learn and write our own xsl.So i am trying and looking for different apporach

Answer (score 1):

You can parse xml data using [jQuery.parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)  and use data of it.

```
$.get('/url_of_the_xml_resource')
  .done(function(data){
    // parse the xml
    data = $.parseXML(data);
    //
    // do anything you want with the parsed data
  })
  .fail(function(){
    alert('something went wrong!');
  })
;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will save `root.xml`'s content as `root.xml.html`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String xmlFile = "root.xml";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(xmlFile)).useDelimiter("\\Z");
    String xmlContent = scanner.next();
    xmlContent = xmlContent.trim().replaceAll("<","&lt;").replaceAll(">","&gt;").replaceAll("\n", "<br />").replaceAll(" ", "&nbsp;");
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(xmlFile+".html");
    out.println("<html><body>" + xmlContent + "</body></html>");
    scanner.close();
    out.close();
}
```

Note: This will retain the XML's original indentation and line breaking.

Comment: thanks for your input...let me try this also..but i want to know what do you mean by retain the XML's original indentation?

Comment: In the `xmlContent` line, remove the `.replaceAll("\n", "<br />").replaceAll(" ", "&nbsp;")` and the indentation will not be retained (then you'll see what I mean).

Comment: actually i want the xml content in some kind of sorting order in html page.But as per your suggestion i tried it was just outputing in html format

Comment: You should update your questions with those additional requirements, then - we can't help you with that if we don't know you need it.

Comment: yes in the starting it was simple one only..but later scenario got changed..sorry for the same

Answer (score -1):

You can use [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html)
and use the method escapeHtml.

```
String yourXmlAsHtmlString = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(yourXmlAsString);
```